# Sentencia if doble condición

Tags: php

Tengo este código:

```
$tipo_vehiculo = $_POST["vehiculo"];

if($tipo_vehiculo == "Ciclomotor"){
    $dgt = 27;
}
elseif($tipo_vehiculo == "Agricola"){
    $dgt = 54;
    $tasa_junta = 11.38;
    $honorarios = $honorarios + 20;
}
else{
    $dgt = 54;
}

if($colaborador == "Beatriz"){
    $honorarios = 25.55;
    $colegio = 4.54;
}
```

Cuando `$colaborador` sea Beatriz los honorarios serán 25.55, hasta aquí sin problemas. El problema es que cuando se dé la circunstancia que el colaborador sea Beatriz y además el `tipo_vehiculo` sea "Agrícola" me incremente los honorarios en 20, y esto es lo que no consigo.

Comment: Me imagino que hay algún motivo para no hacerlo, pero... ¿por qué no simplemente mover el `if` del `$colaborador` encima del condicional que comprueba el `$tipo_vehiculo`?

Comment: Hola Jose, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla) y anímate a [buscar y contestar preguntas de PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) para ayudar a otros usuarios. Un saludo.

Comment: Una pregunta ¿`$honorarios` (y las otras variables) tienen algún valor **por defecto**? Creo que es un dato importante para sugerir un código optimizado.  Además si la variable no existe antes, aquí `$honorarios = $honorarios + 20;` vas a tener un Warning, porque estás usando la variable sin declararla previamente en el cálculo: `$honorarios + 20`

Comment: Ten también presente que no es `elseif` es `else if`. Cuando se usa para plantillas donde combinas PHP y HTML se usa `elseif():` en ese caso el uso es ilegal según la documentación.

Answer (score 3):

Una posible solución podría ser ésta:

```
$tipo_vehiculo = $_POST["vehiculo"];

if($tipo_vehiculo == "Ciclomotor"){
    $dgt = 27;
}
elseif($tipo_vehiculo == "Agricola" and $colaborador == "Beatriz"){
    $dgt = 54;
    $tasa_junta = 11.38;
    $honorarios = $honorarios + 20;
}
elseif($colaborador == "Beatriz"){
    $honorarios = 25.55;
    $colegio = 4.54;
}
else{
    $dgt = 54;
}
```

Si `$tipo_vehiculo` **NO** es "Agrícola", entonces pasará a la siguiente condición del if preguntando si `$colaborador == "Beatriz"` en cuyo caso será cierto y realizará solamente esas sentencias.

Échale un ojo a los [operadores lógicos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es primero mirar si colaborador es Beatriz. Una vez has inicializado honorarios si el tipo de vehículo es Agrícola incrementará en 20. También puedes inicializar $dgt = 54 así te ahorras el else y el agrícola.

```
$tipo_vehiculo = $_POST["vehiculo"];
$dgt = 54; //Inicializacion
if($colaborador == "Beatriz") {
    $honorarios = 25.55;
    $colegio = 4.54;
}

//Condicionales tipo de vehículo
if($tipo_vehiculo == "Ciclomotor") {
    $dgt = 27;
} elseif($tipo_vehiculo == "Agricola") {
    $tasa_junta = 11.38;
    $honorarios = $honorarios + 20;
}
```

En la solución más votada no se tiene en cuenta el caso en que el vehiculo es Agrícola. Sólo tiene en cuenta si es Agrícola y Beatriz. Por tanto el comportamiento del código es diferente. Si colaborador es Pepe y vehículo Agrícola no se inicializará $tasa_junta = 11.38; ...

Answer (score 0):

Esto es simple, solo en la línea donde haces la condición usa:

```
elseif($tipo_vehiculo == "Agricola" and $colaborador != "Beatriz"){
```